# Brother HL-4140CN Factory Reset - forgotten PIN

Tags: printer, brother-printer

I want to reset my printer to factory defaults, I found KNOW HOW in documentacion, but I previous set up an PIN/Password and I forgot this PIN/password, how to reset this printer to Factory Defaults with setup PIN/Password in it?

Answer (score 0):

This [Brother support site](http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=hl4140cn_eu&faqid=faq00002496_000) claims a network reset does a full factory reset, including resetting the password. According to the [Network User's Guide](http://support.brother.com/g/b/manuallist.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=hl4140cn_eu&flang=English&type3=122&type2=6) (pg 35), you can do a network reset from the front panel as follows:

Press + or - to choose Network and press OK

Press + or - to choose Network reset and press OK

Press + to choose Reset

Press + to choose Yes for Reboot

Wait for the printer to restart.